# Posting Data With Url Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, post, url-rewriting

I have a page that allows people to go to a main page, located at

```
mywebsite.com/page
```

[image]

The user is prompted with a username and password input box. If the user enters in only a username, they will go to the associated page (url rewriting) located at

```
mywebsite.com/page/username
```

If they provide a password as well, they are able to edit the data at

```
mywebsite.com/page/username
```

The issue I'm running into, is there is some form validation done when the user clicks submit (POST), some validation is done to make sure the user searched for exists in the database.

If the user exists, my goal is to redirect the page from

```
mywebsite.com/page
```

to

```
mywebsite.com/page/username
```

and have the ability to know whether or not the user entered the correct password (meaning they can change the data) or if they are only able to view it.

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]

FallbackResource page.php
```

Which deals with the url rewriting and showing a custom 404 page if the page isn't found.

It seems like the combination of the url rewriting and POSTing data isn't working how I'd like it to and I'm unsure how to get this functionality to work.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what exactly is the problem, but I would create an AJAX request with the user/pass data, then PHP checks credentials in DB and returns the redirect URL according to it.